# What is the difference between these two lines of code?

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently started learning PHP Laravel and I have come across this code:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/')}}">Welcome Page</a>
```

This is different to what I have learned in basic HTML:

```
<a href="/">Welcome Page</a>
```

Although both lines of code provides same result and gets routed to welcome page. Then what is the difference between both?

Answer (score 1):

The `URL::to()` generate a fully qualified URL for the root of the application based on the **application's base URL** configuration, which is defined in the **config/app.php** file. This means that if you have a specific base URL configured in your Laravel application, it will be used when generating the URL.
and if you change it later or change the structure of your server, you don't have to chnage all urls in you app.